# Dropbox wouldn't use Cisco AnyConnect's VPN connection

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, dropbox, cisco-anyconnect

My other apps work perfectly well with Cisco AnyConnect. However, Dropbox doesn't seem to be able to proxy its traffic through the VPN connection.

After some Googling it appears to me that Cisco Anyconnect runs on port 443, which is the `HTTPS/SSL` port.

However in Dropbox proxy settings tab I cannot find the proxy setting for "`HTTPS`". It only has `HTTP`, `SOCKS4` and `SOCKS5` (The option "automatically detect proxy settings" doesn't work).

Does that mean there is no way for Dropbox to utilize this VPN?

Comment: From your browser, can you connect to [https://www.dropbox.com](https://www.dropbox.com) over the VPN?
If yes, what proxy settings do you have in your browser?